# Design issue in constructor overloading

Tags: java

I am working on existing code to enhance the functionality.

In existing code I saw there are multiple constructors with string parameters. like

```
public class A {
    public A(String a){
    }

    public A(String a, String b){
    }

    public A(String a, String b, String c){
    }
}
```

While enhancement i found that i need to add another string parameter to the constructor.
However this seems to be problem, there could be another enhancement in that i have to add anther string.

I want to avoid such scenario.

What could be the best design to avoid such scenario?

Is good solution is to use HashMap?

Comment: Is this about Java? (You haven't specified the language in your question. I'm only inferring based on the mention of `HashMap`.)

Comment: Yes you can say this is about java. but this issue can arise in any language.

Comment: I've added the tag. For future questions, please be more specific in your question to start with - very often different languages encourage different design idioms.

Comment: Can't you just keep a Collection of Strings as an instance variable? Without telling us what these Strings represent, we can only guess.

Comment: @maenu didn't get your question.

Comment: I wanted to know what these Strings a, b, c are used for. From your comment to an answer, I got that these are meta-data properties about a file. If you have a small, finite set of possible properties, then your are fine with the constructor overloading. If there are a lot of such properties, the builder approach is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is good solution is to use HashMap?

It's not really clear what problem you're trying to solve, but you might want to consider encapsulating the parameters in another class - perhaps one which is mutable, following the builder pattern. That would leave you with something like:

```
FooParams params = new FooParams().withA("a value")
                                  .withB("b value")
                                  .withC("c value");
Foo foo = new Foo(params);
```

(You could even have a `buildFoo()` method in `FooParams` to keep the whole thing fluent.)

Answer (score 2):

Try with a solution that uses [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

```
public class A {
    public A(String ... args) {
        // Add some logic that validates number of input parameters etc.

        for (String arg : args) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
A a1 = new A("tagA: value1", "tagB: value2", "tagC: value3");
A a2 = new A();
A a3 = new A("<tagA>234</tagA>");
```

Comment: This could work, but then the argument order would still need to be fixed & known ahead of time. I think the issue becomes that if each arg is a String, it's not always obvious what that order is. I like the Builder pattern idea a bit more, if only because it simulates named arguments.

Comment: @DougSwain Agree on that. But since the OP hasn't told us what his class is for then maybe this is a valid solution. Maybe he wants to take just a bunch of strings and manipulate.